# How do I filter schtasks output with regular expressions in Windows CMD to return blocks of results containing "Schedule Type: Daily"?

Tags: regex, windows, cmd, findstr

How do I filter schtasks output with regular expressions in Windows CMD to return blocks of results containing "Schedule Type: Daily"?

I want to be able to filter the blocks of results containing "Schedule Type: Daily" with something like this:

```
schtasks /query /fo LIST /v | findstr /r "\n\n[.|\n]*Daily[.|\n]*\n\n"
```

So here is an example of one result block I would like the command to return:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way using the more complete regex capability in PowerShell to find the Schedule Type: Daily tasks.

```
& schtasks.exe /query /fo LIST /v |
    ForEach-Object {
        if ($_ -match '^TaskName:\s*(.*)$') { $CurrentTask = $Matches[1] }
        if ($_ -match '^Schedule Type:\s*Daily\s*$') { $CurrentTask }
    }
```

If you must run this from cmd.exe, the following might be used.

```
@powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "& schtasks.exe /query /fo LIST /v |" ^
        "ForEach-Object {" ^
            "if ($_ -match '^TaskName:\s*(.*)$') { $CurrentTask = $Matches[1] }" ^
            "if ($_ -match '^Schedule Type:\s*Daily\s*$') { $CurrentTask }" ^
        "}"
```

Comment: Perfect, that did the trick! Thanks for that, very much appreciated... Powershell always looks so awkward and foreign to me but I guess I just can't handle the power... You are my hero!!!

Comment: Is there an easy way to add additional pieces of info such as "Next Run Time" and "Task to Run"?

Comment: @spookymonkey, yes, there is a way (pretty easy) to add additional fields to the output. I would recommend using `schtasks.exe /Query /FO CSV /V` to produce a .csv file. That can easily be imported to a spreadsheet or read using `Import-Csv` in PowerShell. If you need help, please post the code you are trying to make work as text into a new question.